# Running a progress bar from another class doesnt work

Tags: java

I'm trying to update a progressbar from another class on different thread then the main one.

but its not working for me, I dont know why
so I've created a class called BarThread.java

```
class BarThread extends Thread {
  ClassificationV4 classObj = new ClassificationV4();


  JProgressBar progressBar;

  public BarThread(JProgressBar bar) {
    progressBar = bar;
  }

  public void run() {
    int minimum = 0;
    int maximum = classObj.getMaximumLength();
    for (int i = minimum; i < maximum; i++) {
      try {
        int value = progressBar.getValue();
        progressBar.setValue(value + 1);

        Thread.sleep(classObj.getSleepTime());
      } catch (InterruptedException ignoredException) {}
    }
  }
}
```

and here I created an anonymous thread to run the progress bar inside on of my methods

```
 //create anonymous thread
new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    Thread stepper = new BarThread(jProgressBar1);
    stepper.start();
  }
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Swing is [not thread safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading). You have to update your `JProgressBar` in the dispatcher (main) thread.

> In general Swing is not thread safe. All Swing components and related classes, unless otherwise documented, must be accessed on the event dispatching thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update UI directly from non-UI thread. Only main thread can update view/UI. If your thread want to update UI, use activity.runOnUiThread()

Official document can found here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

This code may help you.

```
class BarThread extends Thread {
    ClassificationV4 classObj = new ClassificationV4();

    JProgressBar progressBar;
    Activity activity;

    public BarThread(Activity activity, JProgressBar bar) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.progressBar = bar;
    }

    public void run() {
        int minimum = 0;
        int maximum = classObj.getMaximumLength();
        for (int i = minimum; i < maximum; i++) {
            try {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int value = progressBar.getValue();
                        progressBar.setValue(value + 1);
                    }
                });

                Thread.sleep(classObj.getSleepTime());
            } catch (InterruptedException ignoredException) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call from Anonymous thread

```
new Thread() {
public void run() {
    Thread stepper = new BarThread(activity, jProgressBar1);
    stepper.start();
  }
};
```

Comment: I think OP is just using Java with Swing, not Android. Therefore, `Activity` is not available.

Comment: yeah I didnt found Activity class